# How to completely erase Postfix

Tags: command-line, 18.04, uninstall, postfix

I install Postfix on my Ubuntu server 18.04

I modified the configuration of the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

I made mistakes and I want to restore the original file. So I uninstalled Postfix :

```
$ sudo apt remove postfix && apt purge postfix
$ sudo autoremove
```

When I install Postfix again, the installation does not ask the questions like on the first installation. I still have my previous configuration. Why can not I reset the Postfix configuration ?

If I reconfigure Postfix, I still have the previous configuration :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Comment: `remove` does NOT delete the settings files in /etc. However, you are in luck: `purge` does.

Comment: Your `apt purge` command was missing the `sudo` so would **not** have been executed as you provided the command in your question.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge postfix` then check that `/etc/postfix` was deleted

Comment: I used these two commands and it worked like a charm:
`$sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove postfix`
`$sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove postfix`

Comment: Purge will not delete manually edited config files / directories, so those will need to be manually removed with rm.

Answer (score 10):

To completely remove the package and all its configuration files:

```
sudo apt purge postfix
```

You can check if it's uninstalled by checking if the service is running:

```
systemctl status postfix
```

It then should say:

```
Unit postfix.service could not be found.
```

You can then reinstall it.

Comment: Not sure how this answer is different to what is found in the comments for the question. It also does not take into account the need to manually remove some files from the postfix directories in `/etc` 

Comment: @matigo it also removes everything

Comment: @matigo the comments should have been posted as answers instead - Marcii03 did the right thing